# How much reliable Google's Geocode Web Service

Tags: google-api

My site is using Google's Geo-code Webservice to get latitude and longitude of a address and based on returned coordinates, it is calculating distance between this and another coordinates.

As I feel that Google may return coordinates based on only city even though user enters in-correct address. I am calculating prices based on distance between both points and these are in 0-50 KM.

Can anybody tell me how effective is this as I think it may return incorrect distances.

Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if the user enters an incorrect address, it will return a more general coordinate. However, the response from the service also contains a flag indicating that the match was only partial.

Check for `partial_match` under Results

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Results

Comment: I have tried few of the address that are correct but it is showing partial_match in all of them but yes If I use only city name + street name than it does not show partial_match tag all the time.

Comment: @Acharya, I'm don't understand why this isn't what you wanted. You wanted to know if Google was returning partial matches, right?